# Listing all files of a directory using C++ in Linux is not working

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04

I used following code.

```
dp = opendir( dir.c_str() );

while ((dirp = readdir( dp )))
{
    filepath = dir + "/" + dirp->d_name;
}
```

But `dirp->d_name` value is as follows.

> .\000\000\000\004\324E\020\000\000\000\000\000\324!+^S\361Tf\030\000\004..\000\000\004\237X\n\000\000\000\000\000fJ\035\224\321M\264l(\000\bFontTest1.pdf\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\b\236X\n\000\000\000\000\000\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\177(\000\bproject_report.pdf\000\000\b

Comment: Have you checked the value of `dp`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so others can reproduce this issue

Comment: Show the declarations of the relevant names.

Comment: '.\0' seems valid as a C 'string' for current directory for some version of formatting/rendering.

Comment: I am trying to open /home/mjc_in1/pdftestcases in Ubuntu. In this case  dirp->d_name shows all file names in between some junk characters. While ideally it should have shown one file name at a time without any junk characters.

Comment: DIR *dp;
  struct dirent *dirp;

Comment: Your debugger is having a bad hair day.

Comment: It looks like your are reading the content of the directory itself (see `.`, `..`, `FontTest1.pdf`, etc?) and not a single entry of it. Don't know how you debugged it, but your are printing the wrong value.

Comment: It is as if your compiler somehow got the wrong definition of `struct dirent`, so that your pointer points to the data area, but the offset of the `d_name` field within that data is wrong.  Is it possible that you're mixing your code with some outdated library?

Comment: Its not a problem mixing with some outdated library because even a simple standalone main program is giving the same output.

Answer (score 2):

Are you perhaps mis-handling the "." and ".." dirs?  (every dir has them)

I excluded them with:

```
std::string fn(ent->dname);
if(fn ==  ".") { if(dbg2) { std::cout << "S_DOT" << std::endl; } continue;}
if(fn == "..") { if(dbg2) { std::cout << "D_DOT" << std::endl; } continue;}
```

... prior to handling the various d_types

```
switch(ent->d_type)
{
case DT_UNKNOWN: {...}
case DT_DIR:     {...}
// ... etc
}
```

The "continue" jumped to the beginning of the loop processing dirent entries.

Answer (score 1):

The best cross platform way to do this is if you have the [`filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/experimental/filesystem) library. Unfortunately that's still a Technical Specification right now, so you'll need to either use Boost's version of this library or: `experimental/filesystem`.

Once you have `filesystem` though you can simply use a [`directory_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/directory_iterator):

```
copy(directory_iterator(dir), directory_iterator(), ostream_iterator<path>(cout, "\n"))
```

That example may have been a bit complex. If I can clarify something for you let me know.

In Visual Studio 2015 this code runs if you simply `#include <filesystem>` and do `using namespace tr2::sys`. Unfortunately gcc 5.3 hasn't implemented `directory_iterator.operator++()` yet, so you'll need Boost there or you'll get an error along the lines of:

> Undefined reference to `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::directory_iterator::operator++()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I am able to sort it out by adding following code.
    unsigned char isFile =0x8;
    if ( dirp->d_type == isFile)
        //process it